# Are the metal parts of Wonder Woman's costume affected by magnetism?

Tags: comics, dc, weapon, justice-league, wonder-woman

What are Wonder Woman's weapons made of? By weapons I mean the Bracelets, Sword, Tiara and the parts of her uniform that appear to be metal.

I know they're all mystical in origin, so I'm trying to determine whether or not they act like normal metals and specifically whether or not they can be, or ever have been, affected by magnetism.

Comment: They are made [*of wonder*](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/3e/e6/1d/3ee61ddfacbcae15b4a288a93ebd5a86.jpg)

Comment: Are you planning a Wonder Woman-Magneto fanfic?

Comment: In the real world, most metals are not magnetic.

Comment: Thank You... But if any one can remember the name of the ore that Hephaestus uses to make all of the gear, please let me know... I think I saw it mentioned in one of the New 52 comics but I've been looking for about two months now and I still can't find it.

Answer (score 10):

*Note:  Like all comic book characters, Wonder Woman has been subject to a number of different canons throughout her existence, and as such, there is no one answer to this question.  Her weapons, armor, accoutrements, etc, have changed over time, as have the rules and backstories related to them.*

### Magnets:

- In the Golden Age, [her earrings were magnetic, and allowed her to receive messages from Queen Desira of planet Venus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman#Outfit).
- In *Wonder Woman* [volume 1, issue 107](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_107), she used created a super-magnet and used it to disarm and subdue her opponents, which would be a dangerous tactic if her equipment was also attracted to magnets.  We can probably assume that at this point, her weaponry and armor was non-magnetic.

> Wonder Woman, realizing that something isn't right, goes to a nearby small town and purchases a large quantity of magnets. Then using her super strength fuses them into one giant magnet. When Zugggm and Ronnkn attempt to capture her to make them her prisoner, she hides the magnet until they are too close to get away. Pulling it out of the ground, she draws the aliens (and their metal horses and weapons) to the magnet and flies them off into space demanding to know what planet they came from.

- In *Wonder Woman* [volume 1, issues 303](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_303) and [304](http://dc.wikia.com/wiki/Wonder_Woman_Vol_1_304), (*Mystery of the Magnetic Menace!* and *Polaris Means Peril*, she met a magnet-themed villain called Doctor Polaris (one of the Green Lantern's adversaries, similar in abilities to Marvel's Magneto);  however, he refused to fight her, so we don't know whether his magnetic powers would have affected her.

> After an incident in which a USAF plane is destroyed by a mysterious force, both Steve Trevor and Maj. Keith Griggs make a dual test flight over the area in question. Once there, they behold a gigantic apparition materializing before them, which turns out to be Green Lantern’s old foe Dr. Polaris. Diana Prince becomes Wonder Woman and takes her Robot Plane to the area, fighting the materialized villain to little avail. Dr. Polaris magnetically puts both Trevor’s and Griggs’ planes on a collision course, and Wonder Woman has only seconds left to deal with the situation.
>
> Wonder Woman snags Keith Griggs’s jet with her Magic Lasso and pulls it off-course from Trevor’s plane. Polaris refuses to battle Wonder Woman, though, telling her he is only interested in Green Lantern.

- In [JLA 59, *Joker:  Last Laugh - Bipolar Disorder*](http://www.comicvine.com/jla-59-bipolar-disorder/4000-110975/), Dr. Polaris returns, replaces the earth's "magnetic south pole", and uses his electromagnetic powers to subdue everyone in the Justice League, except Superman and Plastic Man, the only two heroes with no polarized metal on their persons.  Wonder Woman is subdued via the magnetic polarity of her bracelets.

> Indeed, there is [some polarized metal on] everyone: Batman's taser, the Green Lantern's ring, **Wonder Woman's bracelets**, Martian Manhunter's blood (it is red from a lot iron), the little lightning decorations at Flash's head and feet. Superman does not have any metal, but Polaris makes him completely busy [with] the metallic objects extricated from ice.
>   -  [Source](http://birdsofpreysuperheroes.blogspot.com/2014/07/justice-league-of-america-059-bipolar.html)

[image]

### General information about her weapons, armor, and outfit:

More generally, much of her ensemble is derived from the same Greek Mythological origins as her race, the fabled Amazons.  Mythological possessions of the Greek gods have been reforged to arm and armor Wonder Woman.

> **Lasso of Truth**
>   When bound with her lasso, criminals have no choice but to tell the truth. The lasso is unbreakable and infinitely stretchable. It was made by the Greek blacksmith god Hephaestus from the girdle of goddess Aphrodite.
>
> **Magic bracelets**
>   In the story, all Amazons wear special bulletproof bracelets that are symbolic of their temporary enslavement to Hercules in Greek mythological history. When Amazons lose their bracelets they go insane with rage. Additionally, if a villain fuses them together, they weaken the wearer, like kryptonite to Superman.
>
> **Invisible plane**
>   The invisible (or really so translucent as to appear invisible) plane doesn't get an origin until after Marston died. There are several conflicting explanations in the comics over the years - it's either an incarnation of Pegasus the flying unicorn or a morphing robotic substance she calls "Dome." As real-world technology advances, the invisible plane becomes an invisible jet.
>   -  [How Stuff Works](http://entertainment.howstuffworks.com/arts/comic-books/wonder-woman3.htm)

And:

> **Lasso of Truth**
>   The Lasso of Truth forces people to tell the truth. It was forged by Hephaestus from the Golden Girdle of Gaea that Antiope had once worn. It is able to restore people's lost memories get rid of illusions or cause illusions to those it holds and heal the holder's body cure insanity and protect people who are in close proximity to it from magical attacks. In the golden age version the lasso could also take on a rigid form and hold people aloft from a great distance away. During these eras, the lasso also forced those who were bound by it to act as the holder demanded. This trait also affected Wonder Woman. A non-combat application of the lasso is that it can be used to change Diana's clothes as long as those clothes are "in the right frequency" as the lasso. Although this was a plot device used more often in the golden and silver age in has been used on occasion in modern comics as for instance one time Diana transformed into a Miss America costume.
>
> **Bracelets of Victory**
>   These are a pair of steel cuffs that are indestructible because they were created from the remains of Zeus’s Aegis shield. Wonder Woman can use her super reflexes to deflect projectiles, blades, punches, or any form of offensive attack used against her (including Darkseid’s Omega Beams). She can also use them to deflect an object back into her enemies. When Diana crosses them to protect her from impact with larger projectiles as well as damage inflicted by explosions and collisions with hard surfaces, the bracelets generate a small energy shield. In recent events, Diana has learned how to emit a devastating magic lightning attack from her bracelets do to their link with Zeus. This attack can even strike Gods and Goddesses down with a powerful strike, and this attack can even work underwater. In the golden age these were items of submission meant to control Amazons. If they were removed from an Amazon, she would launch into an uncontrollable rage, releasing her full power (this was a plot device which subdued many foes, among them the Crimson Centipede). Also during this era, if they were bound together by a man, all her powers were lost, this was only true in the Golden Age. With the launch of the new 52 the golden age bracelets are brought back. Wonder Woman removes her bracelets and go into a "berzerker rage" of power. Wonder Woman's bracelets are what protects her opponents from her intense power in the New 52.
>
> **Royal Tiara**
>   Her tiara is razor sharp and can be used so as to return to her when thrown. It is also magical and can therefore be used to injure those susceptible to magic, such as Superman.
>
> **The Invisible Plane**
>   The invisible plane was Diana’s major means of travel during the Golden and Silver ages as the character did not have the ability of flight. It was controlled telepathically and would appear almost instantly. With the introduction of the power of flight to the character it was a forgotten element of her character until she found the Lansinar Disk. This disc was a piece of alien technology which allowed her to create an invisible version of whatever object or vehicle she visualized it to be. She would use this to create an invisible plane, but it eventually became to be used more to create the Wonder Dome.
>
> **Battle Armour**
>   When faced with a larger threat, Diana will wear her Amazon battle armour for added protection as well as use martial weapons such as swords. Technically speaking as well, as reimagined under the George Perez 1980s reboot, the iconic costume is in fact simply the breastplate of this armour. She will also additionally use a shield for added defense when she deems it necessary.
>
> Martial Weapons
>   Diana is depicted as quite skilled in a number of martial weapons. She has shown to be adept with swords, battle axes and spears. She tends to favour swords though in particularly difficult fights. Her knowledge of martial weapons extends to other less conventional weapons, including broken bottles.
>
> **Magical Sword**
>   On occasions Wonder Woman has employed a magical sword of unknown (though presumably Amazon) origin. This sword has been used most specifically against those with the power of invulnerability as invulnerability generally does not work against magical items. It is generally represented as a short sword. In Wonder Woman (vol. 4) #15, Hephaestus modifies Diana's bracelets so that she can manifest two short swords from them during battle.
>
> Wonder Woman has used these swords many times in the new 52. Specifically in the Justice League and Wonder Woman books.
>
> **Sandals of Hermes**
>   Given to Diana by Hermes, these are no longer in canon, but at one point allowed her to travel between Themyscira and the outside world. These sandals have also been given to Artemis and Cassandra Sandsmark as they also provide the power of flight.
>
> **Gauntlet of Atlas**
>   These gauntlets allow the strength of any who uses them to be increased by ten. She has used these to battle the White Magician in his demon form and Doomsday. When using them Diana has trouble controlling her sudden increase in strength.
>
> **Earrings**
>   Although seemingly only a purely decorative aspect of her costume, in the golden and silver ages, her earrings were sometimes depicted as giving her the ability to breathe in outer space. Gelignite Grenade Earrings and Grappling Hook Bracelet - In her depowered mod girl phase, Diana on rare occasion employed these devices, which were concealed to look like regular parts of her costume. She acquired them from a demolitions expert and villain which she had helped reform. The grenades were strong enough to blast through a thick steel door and the grappling hook could support easily her body weight to aid in climbing.
>
> **Power Rings**
>   For a short time during the Blackest Night crossover, Wonder Woman was empowered by first a Black Power Ring, and then by a violet Power Ring.
>
> **War suits (or uniform)**
>   She has different suits, one which is specified for war and another one which fits for war.
>   -  [Comic Vine](http://www.comicvine.com/wonder-woman/4005-2048/)

And:

> **Aegis of Athena**
>   Her bulletproof bracelets were formed from the remnants of Athena's legendary shield, the Aegis, to be awarded to her champion. The shield was made from the indestructible hide of the great she-goat, Amalthea, who suckled Zeus as an infant. These forearm guards have thus far proven indestructible and able to absorb the impact of incoming attacks, allowing Wonder Woman to deflect automatic weapon fire and energy blasts. Diana can slam the bracelets together to create a wave of concussive force capable of making strong beings like Superman's ears bleed. Recently, she gained the ability to channel Zeus's lightning through her bracelets as well. Zeus explained to her that this power had been contained within the bracelets since their creation, because they were once part of the Aegis, and that he had only recently unlocked it for her use. After the 2011 relaunch of the character, it was revealed that Diana was the daughter of Zeus and Hippolyta and that the bracelets are able to keep the powers she has inherited from Zeus in check. In addition, Hephaestus has modified the bracelets to allow Wonder Woman the sorcerous ability to manifest a sword of grayish metal from each bracelet. Each sword, marked with a red star, takes shape from a flash of lightning, and when Wonder Woman is done with them, the swords disappear, supposedly, back into her bracelets. As such, she has produced other weapons from the bracelets in this way such as a bow that fires explosive arrows, spears and energy bolts among others.
>
> **Lariat of Hestia**
>   The Lasso of Truth, or Lariat of Hestia, was forged by Hephaestus from the golden girdle of Gaea. It compels all beings who come into contact with it to tell the absolute truth and is virtually indestructible; in Identity Crisis, Green Arrow mistakenly describes it as "the only lie detector designed by Zeus." The only times it has been broken were when Wonder Woman herself refused to accept the truth revealed by the lasso, such as when she confronted Rama Khan of Jarhanpur, and by Bizarro in Matt Wagner's non-canonical Batman/Superman/Wonder Woman: Trinity. It also at one time had the power to force anyone caught to obey any command given them, even overriding the mind control of others; this was effective enough to defeat strong-willed beings like Captain Marvel. Diana wields the lasso with great precision and accuracy and can use it as a whip or noose.
>
> **Other items**
>   Diana occasionally uses additional weaponry in formal battle, such as ceremonial golden armour with golden wings, pteruges, chest-plate, and golden helmet in the shape of an eagle's head. She possesses a magical sword forged by Hephaestus that is sharp enough to cut the electrons off an atom.
>
> As early as the 1950s, Wonder Woman's Tiara has also been used as a razor-edged throwing weapon, returning to her like a boomerang. The Tiara allows Wonder Woman to be invulnerable from telepathic attacks. It allows for Diana to telepathically contact people such as the Amazons back on Themyscira using the telepathic power of the red star ruby in the center of her Tiara.
>
> The Golden, Silver, and Bronze Age portrayals of Wonder Woman showed her using a silent and Invisible plane that could be controlled by mental command via her Tiara and fly at speeds up to 3000 miles her hour. Its appearance has varied over time; originally it had a propeller, while later it was drawn as a jet aircraft resembling a stealth aircraft.
>
> During the golden age Wonder Woman possessed a Purple Ray capable of healing even a fatal gunshot wound to the brain. She also possessed a Mental Radio that could let her receive messages from those in need.
>
> As a recent temporary inductee into the Star Sapphires, Wonder Woman gained access to the violet power ring of love. This ring allowed her to alter her costume at will, create solid-light energy constructs, and reveal a person's true love to them. She was able to combine the energy with her lasso to enhance its ability.
>   -  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonder_Woman)